# C# Memory issue using bitmaps for creating a screenrecorder

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, bitmap, dispose

Im developing a screen recorder but having problems with the bitmaps and disposing them. The problem is that ram is being eaten fast. Then i started wondering if it was bad practice creating a screen recorder using bitmaps?

I tried Bitmap.Dispose() but then i get a System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' error.

So the 2 questions i have:

1. Is it bad practice creating a screen recorder using Bitmap?
2. Any idea how to solve the memory issue?

Below is some code, after using the videoFileWriter i tried disposing the image since it would not have been usefull but still it crashes.

Thank you for your time.

```
using (Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
        {
            graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmpImage.Size);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmpImage;

            lblTime.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
            videoFileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bmpImage);
        }
```

Comment: You should always dispose graphics after using it. Also, you don't have to keep recreating Bitmap and graphic, you can just reuse them for each frame

Comment: That code will cause issues because after running it, `pictureBox1.Image` will contain a disposed image. The image should obviously not be disposed before you're done using it.